# Is it possible to passing data in same PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php

I have a button (someone created it and I need to edit) which is saved to `$elisting` in employee.php. The button will go to javascript function named `edit()`. `$elisting` code are below:

```
$elisting ="";

    $queryf = "select employee.id as myid,jobtitle,info,locid,deptid,gender,dob,emid,employee$cid.name,username,dept,datejoin,location.name as loc from  employee

        left join location on location$cid.id = employee.locid 

        inner join department on department.id = employee.deptid order by username

    ";

    $resultf = pg_query($queryf); 

    $numrows = pg_numrows($resultf);

    while ($rowf = pg_fetch_array($resultf)) {

        $ct=$ct+1;

        $myid = $rowf[myid];

        $uname = $rowf[username];

        $loc1 = $rowf[loc];

        $dept = $rowf[dept];

        $date = $rowf[datejoin];

        $name = $rowf[name];

        $emid = $rowf[emid];

        $dob = $rowf[dob];

        $gender = $rowf[gender];

        $job = $rowf[jobtitle];

        $info = $rowf[info];

        $datejoin = $rowf[datejoin];

        $locid = $rowf[locid];

        $deptid = $rowf[deptid];

        $newbal = $rowf[newbal];

        $templatelist = "";

        $tempcn = 0;

        $querytemp = "select tid,ltype from leaveatemplate$cid where username='$uname' order by tid desc";

        $resulttemp = pg_query($querytemp); 

        while ($rowtemp = pg_fetch_array($resulttemp)) {

            $tempcn = $tempcn +1;

            $tid = $rowtemp[tid];

            $ltype = $rowtemp[ltype];

            if($tempcn=="1")

                $templatelist = "$ltype|$tid";

            else

                $templatelist = $templatelist.","."$ltype|$tid";

        }

$elisting=$elisting."<tr><td align=\"center\">$uname</td><td align=\"center\">$loc1</td><td align=\"center\">$dept</td>
        <td align=\"center\">$date</td>
        <td align=\"center\"><a><button class=\"btn btn-mini\"data-toggle=\"modal\"href=\"#long\"
        onClick=\"javascript:edit('$name','$uname','$emid','$dob','$gender','$job','$info','$datejoin','$locid','$deptid','$myid','$templatelist');\"><i class=\"icon-pencil\"></i></a>
```

Here are javascript `edit()` code:

```
function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){
        document.getElementById("frm").id.value=k;
      document.getElementById("frm").name.value=a;
        document.getElementById("frm").username.value=b;
        document.getElementById("frm").emid.value=c;
      document.getElementById("frm").dob.value=d;
        setCheckedValue(document.forms['frm'].elements['gender'],e);
        document.getElementById("frm").job.value=f;
        document.getElementById("frm").info.value=g;
        document.getElementById("frm").datejoin.value=h;
        document.getElementById('locid').value=i;
        document.getElementById('deptid').value=m;

      var params = b;
      window.location.href="http://192.168.1.5/eleave/employee.php?lapplicant=" + params;

        var myTemp = l;
        var mySplitResult = myTemp.split(",");
        for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
            cval = mySplitResult[i];
            myval = cval.split("|");
            val1 = myval[0];
            val2 = myval[1];
            document.getElementById('temp'+val1).value= val2;
        }
```

Since I failed to try many ways to get `b` in `edit()`, so I need to find the way to get $uname in `$elisting` and send it to `$llisting` in the same PHP file (employee.php) which the code are below:

```
$llisting ="";

    $ct=0;

    //leave code
    $ccompassionate = "3";
    $cemergency = "4";
    $cmaternity = "5";
    $cmedical = "6";
    $cannual = "2";

    //leave value
    $compassionate = 2;
    $emergency = 5;
    $maternity = 60;
    $medical = 20;

    $lapplicant = $_POST['lapplicant'];

    $querye = "select leavetype.id, leavetype.ltype, leaves.leave from leavetype,leaves where username='".$_SESSION["username"]."'";

        $resulte = pg_query($querye); 

        while ($rowe = pg_fetch_array($resulte)) {

            $ct=$ct+1;

            $lid = $rowe[id];

            $ltype = $rowe[ltype];

            $leave = $rowe[leave];  

        if ($lid == $ccompassionate) {
            $compassionate_query = pg_query("select ltotal from leave where lapplicant='".$lapplicant."' and ltype='".$ccompassionate."'");
            if (count($compassionate_query) > 0) {
                foreach ($compassionate_query as $data) {
                    $total_compassionate = $total_compassionate + $data['total'];
                    $value = $compassionate - $total_compassionate;
                }

            } else {
                $value = $compassionate;
            }
$llisting=$llisting."<tr><td align=\"center\">$ct</td><td>$ltype</td><td><input type='text' value='$lapplicant'></td><td align=\"center\">";

        $llisting=$llisting."<select name=\"temp$lid\" id=\"temp$lid\" class=\"span12\"><option value=\"0\"> - </option> $tlisting</select>";

        $llisting=$llisting."</td></tr>\n";
```

Anyone have an idea to get `$uname` in `$elisting` and send to `$llisting`?

And also, how can `'$name','$uname','$emid','$dob','$gender','$job','$info','$datejoin','$locid','$deptid','$myid','$templatelist'` in `$elisting` change to `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l` in `edit()`, I'm new in Javascript so I don't understand how can it change?

Thank you for help..

[image]

this is the code where `href="#long"` called:

```
<div id="long" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" data-replace="true" data-width="760">
    <div class="modal-header"><h3>Employee Profile</h3></div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="Post" name="frm" id="frm">
```

Code to call html page:

```
if($msg!="") $alert= "<div class=\"alert\"><i class=\"icon-info-sign\"></i> $msg</div><p>&nbsp;</p>";

    $source2 = file_get_contents('http://'.$_SESSION["url"].'/cgi-bin/vo/'.$_SESSION["sessid"].'.interface.designer.vo?file=eleave/employee.htm');

    $html2 = str_replace("[templateurl]",$templateurl,$source2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[alert]",$alert ,$html2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[elisting]",$elisting ,$html2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[ulisting]",$ulisting ,$html2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[locationlisting]",$locationlisting ,$html2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[deptlisting]",$deptlisting ,$html2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[llisting]",$llisting ,$html2);

    $html2 = str_replace("[wfid]","sid=$sid" ,$html2);

    echo $html2;
```

Comment: in your Javascript put this only `function edit(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l){ alert(b); }` what you get?

Comment: Still show same page, Sir.. Nothing changing.. I got confuse..

Comment: use print_r() on your PHP to debug and console.log() to see what you are doing. and go step by step.

Comment: alert in JS is simply pops out a box on the same page only. If you are using Chrome, hit Shift+Ctrl+J to open the console. Open the console, and click to trigger the edit() function and see if you get anything.

Comment: the console just showed nothing, sir..

Comment: Please please please dont call your variables a,b,c etc. Its totally unreadable for any future developer

Comment: That's why I asked, sir. I got confuse why a,b,c etc is in edit(), not $uname, $name etc.

Comment: by the way, I don't see the opening `a` tag? and also just check if the function `edit()` is actually triggered.

Comment: `document.getElementById('deptid').value=m m;` remove the last m, it is an error in JS

Comment: still showed nothing, sir. I uploaded the picture above.

Comment: too much stuff, perhaps refer to my answer below\, will keep updating. Please try the basic thing first.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the basic first, I have no problem with this one.

In JS:

```
<script>
    function TestTriggered(name){
        alert("the function triggered!");
        alert("My name is: " + name);
    }
</script>
```

On the HTML part

```
<input type="button" name="myButton" onClick="javascript:TestTriggered('John');" value="Please click"/>
```

Please try this first and see how thing works.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: yes I know, since the code is long, it is not really suits the comment section. This is to show how things works then we can expand this to user's question accordingly.

Comment: I tried to put your code and it showed blank page and `NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://192.168.1.5/eleave/employee.php?sid=SID421464131stwptwbply497.`
Then I tried to edit my code: `<input type='button' class=\"btn btn-mini\"data-toggle=\"modal\"href=\"#long\"
  onClick=\"javascript:testtriggered('Nana');\">`, 
and it showed the same page from `edit()` without data inside the text field. and there was an error: `ReferenceError: testtriggered is not defined.` Is it related to `href=\"#long\"`? long is an id for div contains the form and data from $elisting.

Comment: you have to define the function `testtriggered` first. remove `href` as it is used to navigate to other pages

Comment: I have sir, in html page.. And when I deleted the `href='#long'`, nothing appeared just error in console. `ReferenceError: testtriggered is not defined`

Comment: you might be mixing up stuff. Just put my code in a new page. Just put my above code in the answer and run the page.

Comment: How can I call the new file name, in that code? Cause there is no details about that. I've updated the code to show html page, which I don't know how to put the new page. Hope it can help.